# RandomResizeCrop: method to obtain the exact scale value that the function is using

Tags: pytorch

I am using the RandomResizeCrop function in PyTorch with a random scale parameter set in the range (0.8, 1.0). Is there a method to obtain the exact scale value that the function is using within this specified range?

I need this information for ensuring reproducibility in my experiments. Thanks!!